# native method not found when I change the package name

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

In my project when I change my package name , I got following error.
I surf the net but no useful data.
In some case I found that my method shouldn't be static and when I remove static 
it set that this method must be static. 
any suggestion to solve this issue
thanks in advance
this is my error:

Native method not found:

```
com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.get_number_of_processors:()I
        at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.get_number_of_processors(Native Method)
        at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.runServer(JNIServer.java:27)
        at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.FreebloksActivity.startNewGame(FreebloksActivity.java:520)
        at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.FreebloksActivity$16.onClick(FreebloksActivity.java:774)
        at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.ColorListDialog.onItemClick(ColorListDialog.java:79)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3339)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this my code:

```
public class JNIServer {
final static String tag = JNIServer.class.getSimpleName();

/* unfortunately Runtime.availableProcessors() returns only the number of online cores */
public static native int get_number_of_processors();

private static native int native_run_server(int game_mode, int field_size_x, int field_size_y, int ki_mode, int ki_threads);

private static native int native_resume_server(
        int field_size_x,
        int field_size_y,
        int current_player,
        int spieler[],
        int field_data[],
        int player_stone_data[],
        int game_mode,
        int ki_mode,
        int ki_threads);


public static void runServer(Spielleiter spiel, int game_mode, int field_size, int ki_mode) {
    int ki_threads = get_number_of_processors();

    if (spiel == null)
        native_run_server(game_mode, field_size, field_size, ki_mode, ki_threads);
    else {
        int player_stones_available[] = new int[Stone.STONE_COUNT_ALL_SHAPES * 4];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < Stone.STONE_COUNT_ALL_SHAPES; j++)
                player_stones_available[i * Stone.STONE_COUNT_ALL_SHAPES + j] = spiel.get_player(i).get_stone(j).get_available();

        native_resume_server(
                spiel.m_field_size_x,
                spiel.m_field_size_y,
                spiel.current_player(),
                spiel.spieler,
                spiel.get_game_field(),
                player_stones_available,
                game_mode,
                ki_mode,
                ki_threads);
    }
}

static {
    Log.d(tag, "loading server.so");
    System.loadLibrary("server");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `native` keyword everywhere? It's supposed to mean something is implemented in another language, which doesn't seem to be the case here thus causes this error.

Comment: If you do have implementations in another language, the package changing probably breaks the lookup of the native code. Did you move that to the new package too?

Comment: yes, I have jni folder in my project. how I can rebuild it?